# keycloak 16.1.0 setup twitter identity providers return exceptionCode=[8e063946-fe607b48]

Tags: twitter, keycloak

need help please. I am running keycloak 16.1.0 by docker. I already double check the value of client id and client secret given from twitter. But getting messages displayed *Could not send authentication request to identity provider.*.

There is some information from logs that saying

```
message - Could not authenticate you.
code - 32

Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=8e063946 or
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=fe607b48
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[8e063946-fe607b48], statusCode=401, message=Could not authenticate you., code=32, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=4.0.7}
    at org.twitter4j@4.0.7//twitter4j.HttpClientImpl.handleRequest(HttpClientImpl.java:170)
    at org.twitter4j@4.0.7//twitter4j.HttpClientBase.request(HttpClientBase.java:57)
    at org.twitter4j@4.0.7//twitter4j.HttpClientBase.post(HttpClientBase.java:86)
    at org.twitter4j@4.0.7//twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.getOAuthRequestToken(OAuthAuthorization.java:115)
    at org.twitter4j@4.0.7//twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.getOAuthRequestToken(OAuthAuthorization.java:92)
    at org.twitter4j@4.0.7//twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.getOAuthRequestToken(TwitterBaseImpl.java:296)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@16.1.0//org.keycloak.social.twitter.TwitterIdentityProvider.performLogin(TwitterIdentityProvider.java:94)
    ... 77 more
```

here is some additional info

```
bash-4.4$ java --version
openjdk 11.0.13 2021-10-19 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.13+8-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.13+8-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
bash-4.4$ date
Thu Dec 23 08:43:02 UTC 2021
```

[image]

what should i do to solve?

Comment: Lots of things to check here. Is the system clock accurate? Have you setup an OAuth 1.0a authentication option in the Twitter Developer Portal? Are you able to use your keys and tokens outside of Keycloak using e.g. Postman?

Comment: @AndyPiper thanks for response. yes, I set up both Oauth1.0 and Oauth2 .not yet try to use key and tokens outside keycloak, will check it later. For clock is accurate I think

Comment: Keycloak is using Twitter4J which only supports OAuth 1.0a and the Twitter API v1.1. You may need Elevated access to the Twitter API, it will not work with Essential access.

Comment: Hello! Did you manage to fix you problem? How did you fix it?